# multiple buttons on jquery html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

There is a problem with the below code. The second button show it does not work. It doesn't open anything.
The problem is for sure the Show ..if I changed it to class , both do not work.
And I would like in each row the text to be left without any margin , but I couldn't fixed it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Cafeteria Orders Management System</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <style>
        label,
        input {
          display: block;
        }

        input.text {
          margin-bottom: 12px;
          width: 95%;
          padding: .4em;
        }

        fieldset {
          padding: 0;
          border: 0;
          margin-top: 25px;
        }

        td {
          max-width: 120px;
          white-space: nowrap;
        }

        h1 {
          font-size: 1.2em;
          margin: .6em 0;
        }

        div#users-contain {
          width: 300px;
          margin: 20px 0;
        }

        div#users-contain table {
          margin: 1em 0;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          width: 100%;
        }

        div#users-contain table td,
        div#users-contain table th {
          border: 9px solid #eee;
          padding: .6em 120px;
          text-align: left;
        }

        .ui-dialog .ui-state-error {
          padding: .3em;
        }

        .validateTips {
          border: 1px solid transparent;
          padding: 0.3em;
        }

      </style>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(function() {
          var dialog, form,

            // From http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#e-mail-state-%28type=email%29
            emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
            name = $("#name"),
            email = $("#email"),
            password = $("#password"),
            allFields = $([]).add(name).add(email).add(password),
            tips = $(".validateTips");

          function updateTips(t) {
            tips
              .text(t)
              .addClass("ui-state-highlight");
            setTimeout(function() {
              tips.removeClass("ui-state-highlight", 1500);
            }, 500);
          }

          function checkLength(o, n, min, max) {
            if (o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min) {
              o.addClass("ui-state-error");
              updateTips("Length of " + n + " must be between " +
                min + " and " + max + ".");
              return false;
            } else {
              return true;
            }
          }

          function checkRegexp(o, regexp, n) {
            if (!(regexp.test(o.val()))) {
              o.addClass("ui-state-error");
              updateTips(n);
              return false;
            } else {
              return true;
            }
          }

          function addUser() {
            var valid = true;
            allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");

            valid = valid && checkLength(name, "username", 3, 16);
            valid = valid && checkLength(email, "email", 6, 80);
            valid = valid && checkLength(password, "password", 5, 16);

            valid = valid && checkRegexp(name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, spaces and must begin with a letter.");
            valid = valid && checkRegexp(email, emailRegex, "eg. ui@jquery.com");
            valid = valid && checkRegexp(password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9");

            if (valid) {
              $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" +
                "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
                "</tr>");
              dialog.dialog("close");
            }
            return valid;
          }

          dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 400,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {

              Ok: function() {
                dialog.dialog("close");
              }
            },
            close: function() {
              form[0].reset();
              allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
            }
          });

          form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            addUser();
          });

          $("#create-user").button().on("click", function() {
            dialog.dialog("open");
          });
        });

      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="dialog-form" title="Order Details">
        <p class="validateTips">Spicy Sandwitch</p>
        <p class="validateTips">More</p>
        <form>
          <fieldset>
            <label for="name">More Comments</label>
            <p class="validateTips">Sandwitch only lettuce</p>
            <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
            <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
        <h1>Order List:</h1>
        <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
          <thead>
            <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
              <th>Name/Surname</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>Telephone</th>
              <th>Time/Date</th>
              <th>Order Details</th>
              <th>Done</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              </td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
              <td>Lykavitou 12, 2109 Aglantzia</td>
              <td>99123456</td>
              <td>21:00 21/11/16</td>
              <td>
                <button id="create-user">Show</button>
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="1" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
              </td>
              <td>Andreas Georgiou</td>
              <td>Grigori Auxentiou 12, 2109 Aglantzia</td>
              <td>99654789</td>
              <td>20:00 21/11/16</td>
              <td>
                <button id="create-user">Show</button>
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="1" />
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: What's with all the `</html>` and `</body>`s?

Comment: @Turnip I was using an online html viewer and every time I was running the code , it added head and body their name in my code

Comment: `create-user` is used as an ID twice. Use classes instead.

Comment: @Malk I tried but then the buttons didn't worked. Can you help me more? Answer

Answer (score 0):

change in the button attribute id, u cant use more than one id with the same name on your website, you can use class instead of. For example

```
<button class="create-user">Show</button>
```

and in the js u must call to the class

```
$(".create-user")
```

Comment: Thank you, Do you know how to change the contents (text) of each popup in different row? I mean that the text will be different for each order

Answer (score 0):

As was suggested, you will want to use the class attribute and selector.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/5n2h03nL/

**HTML**

```
<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
  <h1>Order List:</h1>
  <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
      <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
        <th>Name/Surname</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Telephone</th>
        <th>Time/Date</th>
        <th>Order Details</th>
        <th>Done</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>Lykavitou 12, 2109 Aglantzia</td>
        <td>99123456</td>
        <td>21:00 21/11/16</td>
        <td>
          <button id="create-user-1" class="showDialog">Show</button>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="1" />
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Andreas Georgiou</td>
        <td>Grigori Auxentiou 12, 2109 Aglantzia</td>
        <td>99654789</td>
        <td>20:00 21/11/16</td>
        <td>
          <button id="create-user-2" class="showDialog">Show</button>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="1" />
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".showDialog").button().on("click", function() {
  dialog.dialog("open");
});
```

In regards to your other comment, you will need to provide more info. If you want the "Show" button to launch the dialog with custom details each time, those details need to be provided from some place. You can make use of `data` attributes on the row, like `<tr data-comments="">` or make an AJAX call to a database. We can't just write that for you, you need to figure out where you want to store those details and how you want to collect them when the button is clicked.

In regards to this question, I suspect you've got the answer. So I would mark one as a answer, take a stab at your next issue, and if needed create a new question.